# Would browser wait on one response or make 3 if I made 3 duplicate GET Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

What if I made 3 duplicate calls in rapid succession (like in milliseconds). Would browser wait on 1 response or make 3 duplicate GET Ajax calls. Would it just assign the response of one to all 3, if not can I force it to do that.

Comment: Hi @Phil I did try it out before posting. I wasn't sure if its coz dev tool doesn't cache. Also I wanted to know how to prevent it. Request you to consider your down vote if you are the one who did.

Answer (score 1):

Depends....

> Browsers limit the number of HTTP connections with the same domain
>   name. This restriction is defined in the HTTP specification (RFC2616).
>   Most modern browsers allow six connections per domain. Most older
>   browsers allow only two connections per domain.

[Reference](https://docs.pushtechnology.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html)

So if there are no pending requests in your case, all 3 can be trigger at the same time. Also note that the limit is for each domain. If your 3 ajax calls ares in 3 different domains (say different CDNs) chances are it will always triggered at same time. (means browser will not wait for response)